# How to moq FromSqlInterpolated?

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

Please, help with moking FromSqlInterpolated method from context.
I have a simple method:

```
public List<UserTag> PrintUserTag(string userId)
    {
        return this.context.UserTag.FromSqlInterpolated($"ctc_sp_UserTag {userId}").ToList();
    }
```

I wrote a test:

```
[Fact]
    public void UserTagTest_ReturnsSuccessResult()
    {
        string userId = "7C8FFA01-94FC-42EA-9C43-5CA7FD0400D1";

        List<UserTag> userTags = new List<UserTag>()
        {
            new UserTag()
            {
                Id = userId,
                UserTagName = "TestName",
                // ..... and others lines
            }
        };

        var mockDbSet = userTags.AsDbSetMock();
        mockContext.Setup(x => x.UserTags).Returns(mockDbSet.Object);
        mockContext.Setup(a =>
                a.Set<UserTag>().FromSqlInterpolated<UserTag>(It.IsAny<FormattableString>())).Returns(mockDbSet.Object);

        var actual = this.repo.PrintUserTag(userId);

        Assert.NotNull(actual);
        // And other Asserts
    }
```

And received this exception:

```
Message: 
System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: ... => ....FromSqlInterpolated<UserTags>(It.IsAny<FormattableString>())
Extension methods (here: RelationalQueryableExtensions.FromSqlInterpolated) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
```

How can I mock this line or rewrite it:

```
mockContext.Setup(a =>
                a.Set<UserTag>().FromSqlInterpolated<UserTag>(It.IsAny<FormattableString>())).Returns(mockDbSet.Object);
```

Comment: Don't use mocks for this. Either test against a real database (like a LocalDB instance) if you want to do integration tests, or lift your tests to a higher level where you don't test the concrete DB layer but extract the data access using interfaces, if you want to do true unit tests. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/testing/) for more.

Comment: You should `mockDbSet.Setup(x => x.FromSqlInterpolated(...))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mock `FromSqlInterpolated` directly as it's extension method. Under the covers it invokes `CreateQuery<T>` on the `DbSet<T>` queryable provider.

If you don't want to set up integration tests, the library [EntityFrameworkCore.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing), which I am the author of, can do it. If you want to have a go at mocking it yourself I'm happy to point you towards the code you'll need, but I'd need to know what version of EFCore you're using as the implementation varies.

The integration tests vs mocking is an opinionated topic. I agree with the advise from MS in that you shouldn't mock a DbContext - it's a complicated dependency that you don't own and it'd be difficult to simulate the behaviour in a mock. Generally I use the in-memory provider which in my experience is a reliable fake however it can't do relational operations.

I treat relational operations as well known dependencies that I am in control of - they are often my stored procedures or functions, I own them - so I don't have a problem mocking them using the mentioned library. They still need to be tested at some point but at least this way I've got options.